# How to restore OnePlus 3 with possibly corrupted partitions?

Tags: cyanogenmod, unbricking, twrp

I don't remember exactly how, but I think TWRP ended up corrupting some of my phone. Regardless, now when I try booting into a recovery other than the CM14 Recovery, I just get a black screen after the OnePlus logo and nothing happens. I have had other problems too, like `CM Bug Report Has Stopped` every startup and app (un)install. I can also install CM14, which I've done multiple times, but stock OxygenOS will not work, and neither will Open GApps. When I sideload these zips it seems to stop midway anyway.

Just for information, my bootloader is unlocked, I currently have CyanogenMod version `14.1-20161119-NIGHTLY-oneplus3` installed, and I tried using MultiROM before (probably the cause, and I probably won't use it again) mostly as an easy backup/ROM switching system as my main ROM didn't like the MultiROM boot addition.

In an attempt to restore full functionality, I have tried all of the wiping options the CM recovery offers, including formatting the `userdata` partition when it couldn't just wipe it (happened the first time). I also tried the [MEGA Unbrick guide](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/guide-mega-unbrick-guide-for-a-hard-bricked-oneplus-3.452634/), which seemed to have incomplete instructions (or something), but in essence I used `fastboot` to flash the full `.rar` file reformatted as a `.zip` file. This just resulted in a black screen for both the main system and the recovery, so I've given up. **Is there a way to restore my OnePlus 3 to its former glory?**

Also, I had a TWRP backup, which not only could I not use but it got deleted after wiping `/data`, but I do have adb backups (stored on a computer) of everything that I could back up.

Below is pasted a log (`/cache/recovery/last_log`) from trying to install Open GApps:

```
[    0.000988] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[    0.001062] Starting recovery (pid 439) on Thu Feb 12 08:37:15 1970
[    0.001451] recovery filesystem table
[    0.001471] =========================
[    0.001476]   0 /boot emmc /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot 0
[    0.001481]   1 /recovery emmc /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/recovery 0
[    0.001485]   2 /system ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system 0
[    0.001489]   3 /data f2fs /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata -16384
[    0.001493]   4 /data ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata -16384
[    0.001499]   5 /cache f2fs /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache 0
[    0.001504]   6 /cache ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache 0
[    0.001508]   7 /persist ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist 0
[    0.001512]   8 /dsp ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/dsp 0
[    0.001516]   9 /firmware vfat /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem 0
[    0.001543]   10 /bt_firmware vfat /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/bluetooth 0
[    0.001547]   11 /misc emmc /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/misc 0
[    0.001553]   12 auto auto /devices/soc/6a00000.ssusb/6a00000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb* 0
[    0.001557]   13 /tmp ramdisk ramdisk 0
[    0.001561]
[    0.015165] locale is [en_US]
[    0.015213] stage is []
[    0.015249] reason is [(null)]
[    0.015413] I:VoldClient thread starting
[    0.015425] I:Connecting to Vold...
[    1.018640] I:VoldClient initialized, storage is emulated
[    1.018661] cannot find/open a drm device: No such file or directory
[    1.018842] fb0 reports (possibly inaccurate):
[    1.018849]   vi.bits_per_pixel = 32
[    1.018854]   vi.red.offset   =   0   .length =   8
[    1.018859]   vi.green.offset =   8   .length =   8
[    1.018863]   vi.blue.offset  =  16   .length =   8
[    1.028066] framebuffer: 0 (1080 x 1920)
[    1.087024]           erasing_text: en_US (133 x 57 @ 1740)
[    1.092802]        no_command_text: en_US (248 x 57 @ 1740)
[    1.097241]             error_text: en_US (94 x 57 @ 1740)
[    1.359150] I:Detected home key, disabling virtual home button
[    1.359179] I:Detected back key, disabling virtual back button
[    1.359186] I:Detected home key, disabling virtual home button
[    1.367919]        installing_text: en_US (453 x 57 @ 1740)
[    1.372464] Command: "/sbin/recovery"
[    1.372482]
[    1.372661] ro.adb.secure=1
[    1.372953] ro.hwui.texture_cache_size=96
[    1.373118] persist.net.doxlat=true
[    1.373158] debug.gralloc.enable_fb_ubwc=1
[    1.373225] ro.alarm_boot=false
[    1.373551] ro.opengles.version=196610
[    1.373557] ro.sf.lcd_density=480
[    1.373662] camera.hal1.packagelist=com.skype.raider,com.whatsapp,com.tencent.mm,com.google.android.GoogleCamera
[    1.373668] persist.camera.llc=1
[    1.373674] persist.camera.imglib.fddsp=1
[    1.373678] persist.camera.llnoise=1
[    1.373711] ro.min_freq_0=307200
[    1.373716] ro.min_freq_4=307200
[    1.373841] ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge=0
[    1.373847] dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant=cortex-a53
[    1.373854] dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features=default
[    1.373858] dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.variant=kryo
[    1.373862] dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.features=default
[    1.373866] dalvik.vm.usejit=true
[    1.373870] dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m
[    1.373876] dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold=500
[    1.373880] dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms=64m
[    1.373884] dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx=512m
[    1.373888] dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree=8m
[    1.373892] dalvik.vm.heapminfree=512k
[    1.373896] dalvik.vm.heapstartsize=8m
[    1.373900] dalvik.vm.appimageformat=lz4
[    1.373904] dalvik.vm.usejitprofiles=true
[    1.373909] dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=256m
[    1.373913] dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt
[    1.373917] dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms=64m
[    1.373921] dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx=64m
[    1.373925] dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization=0.75
[    1.373930] ro.config.ringtone=Orion.ogg
[    1.373934] ro.config.alarm_alert=Hassium.ogg
[    1.373938] ro.config.notification_sound=Argon.ogg
[    1.373942] config.foss.xml=1
[    1.373946] config.foss.path=/system/etc/FOSSConfig.xml
[    1.373994] ro.build.fingerprint=OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3:6.0.1/MMB29M/362280:user/release-keys
[    1.374029] vold.has_adoptable=0
[    1.374036] af.fast_track_multiplier=1
[    1.374040] bt.max.hfpclient.connections=1
[    1.374045] pm.dexopt.boot=verify-profile
[    1.374049] pm.dexopt.ab-ota=speed-profile
[    1.374053] pm.dexopt.install=interpret-only
[    1.374057] pm.dexopt.core-app=speed
[    1.374062] pm.dexopt.bg-dexopt=speed-profile
[    1.374066] pm.dexopt.first-boot=interpret-only
[    1.374070] pm.dexopt.shared-apk=speed
[    1.374074] pm.dexopt.nsys-library=speed
[    1.374078] pm.dexopt.forced-dexopt=speed
[    1.374082] ro.am.reschedule_service=true
[    1.374087] ro.cm.build.version.plat.rev=0
[    1.374091] ro.cm.build.version.plat.sdk=7
[    1.374095] ro.cm.device=oneplus3
[    1.374099] ro.cm.display.version=14.1-20161119-NIGHTLY-oneplus3
[    1.374103] ro.cm.version=14.1-20161119-NIGHTLY-oneplus3
[    1.374107] ro.cm.releasetype=NIGHTLY
[    1.374111] ro.qc.sdk.audio.ssr=false
[    1.374115] ro.qc.sdk.audio.fluencetype=fluence
[    1.374120] ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-oneplus
[    1.374124] ro.com.android.dateformat=MM-dd-yyyy
[    1.374128] ro.com.android.dataroaming=false
[    1.374132] ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist=GoogleGuest
[    1.374136] ro.frp.pst=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/config
[    1.374140] ro.gps.agps_provider=1
[    1.374143] ro.nfc.port=I2C
[    1.374147] ro.sys.fw.bg_apps_limit=60
[    1.374151] ro.sys.sdcardfs=true
[    1.374155] ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
[    1.374159] ro.url.legal.android_privacy=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html
[    1.374165] ro.boot.mode=recovery
[    1.374169] ro.boot.angela=disabled
[    1.374172] ro.boot.secboot=enabled
[    1.374176] ro.boot.selinux=permissive
[    1.374180] ro.boot.baseband=msm
[    1.374184] ro.boot.ftm_mode=ftm_recovery
[    1.374188] ro.boot.hardware=qcom
[    1.374192] ro.boot.serialno=1bc50b8e
[    1.374196] ro.boot.bootdevice=624000.ufshc
[    1.374200] ro.boot.hw_version=16
[    1.374204] ro.boot.rf_version=31
[    1.374207] ro.boot.veritymode=enforcing
[    1.374211] ro.boot.pcba_number=001580306920032400021546
[    1.374215] ro.boot.startupmode=pon1
[    1.374219] ro.boot.project_name=15801
[    1.374223] ro.boot.enable_dm_verity=1
[    1.374227] ro.boot.verifiedbootstate=orange
[    1.374232] ro.hwui.path_cache_size=39
[    1.374236] ro.hwui.layer_cache_size=64
[    1.374240] ro.hwui.gradient_cache_size=1
[    1.374244] ro.hwui.r_buffer_cache_size=12
[    1.374248] ro.hwui.drop_shadow_cache_size=7
[    1.374252] ro.hwui.text_large_cache_width=3072
[    1.374256] ro.hwui.text_small_cache_width=2048
[    1.374259] ro.hwui.text_large_cache_height=2048
[    1.374263] ro.hwui.text_small_cache_height=2048
[    1.374267] ro.hwui.texture_cache_flushrate=0.4
[    1.374271] ro.qcom.dpps.sensortype=3
[    1.374275] ro.wifi.channels=
[    1.374279] ro.allow.mock.location=0
[    1.374283] ro.board.platform=msm8996
[    1.374287] ro.build.id=NDE63X
[    1.374291] ro.build.date=Fri Nov 18 20:23:23 PST 2016
[    1.374295] ro.build.date.utc=1479529403
[    1.374299] ro.build.host=cyanogenmod
[    1.374303] ro.build.tags=test-keys
[    1.374307] ro.build.type=userdebug
[    1.374310] ro.build.user=jenkins
[    1.374314] ro.build.flavor=cm_oneplus3-userdebug
[    1.374319] ro.build.display.id=OnePlus3-userdebug 7.1 NDE63X b60a451bc0 test-keys
[    1.374323] ro.build.product=OnePlus3
[    1.374327] ro.build.selinux=1
[    1.374332] ro.build.version.sdk=25
[    1.374336] ro.build.version.base_os=
[    1.374340] ro.build.version.release=7.1
[    1.374344] ro.build.version.codename=REL
[    1.374347] ro.build.version.incremental=b60a451bc0
[    1.374351] ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0
[    1.374355] ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL
[    1.374359] ro.build.version.security_patch=2016-11-05
[    1.374363] ro.build.description=OnePlus3-user 6.0.1 MMB29M 24 dev-keys
[    1.374367] ro.build.characteristics=nosdcard
[    1.374371] ro.error.receiver.system.apps=org.cyanogenmod.bugreport
[    1.374379] ro.secure=1
[    1.374384] ro.vendor.extension_library=libqti-perfd-client.so
[    1.374388] ro.zygote=zygote64_32
[    1.374392] ro.carrier=unknown
[    1.374396] ro.cmlegal.url=https://cyngn.com/legal/privacy-policy
[    1.374400] ro.display.series=OnePlus 3
[    1.374404] ro.product.cpu.abi=arm64-v8a
[    1.374407] ro.product.cpu.abilist=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
[    1.374411] ro.product.cpu.abilist32=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
[    1.374416] ro.product.cpu.abilist64=arm64-v8a
[    1.374419] ro.product.name=OnePlus3
[    1.374423] ro.product.board=msm8996
[    1.374427] ro.product.brand=OnePlus
[    1.374431] ro.product.model=ONEPLUS A3000
[    1.374435] ro.product.device=OnePlus3
[    1.374439] ro.product.locale=en-US
[    1.374443] ro.product.manufacturer=OnePlus
[    1.374447] ro.product.first_api_level=23
[    1.374451] ro.baseband=msm
[    1.374455] ro.bootmode=recovery
[    1.374459] ro.hardware=qcom
[    1.374463] ro.qualcomm.foss=1
[    1.374467] ro.qualcomm.display.paneltype=1
[    1.374471] ro.revision=0
[    1.374474] ro.serialno=1bc50b8e
[    1.374478] ro.bootimage.build.date=Fri Nov 18 20:23:23 PST 2016
[    1.374482] ro.bootimage.build.date.utc=1479529403
[    1.374486] ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint=OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3:7.1/NDE63X/b60a451bc0:userdebug/test-keys
[    1.374492] ro.telephony.call_ring.multiple=false
[    1.374496] ro.telephony.default_network=22,22
[    1.374500] ro.bootloader=unknown
[    1.374504] ro.debuggable=1
[    1.374508] ro.modversion=14.1-20161119-NIGHTLY-oneplus3
[    1.374512] ro.recovery_id=0x06d0e22fbde974027d595ec41c6c0dc465f949eb000000000000000000000000
[    1.374516] ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode=1
[    1.374520] ro.use_data_netmgrd=true
[    1.374524] drm.service.enabled=true
[    1.374528] sdm.debug.disable_rotator_split=1
[    1.374531] sdm.perf_hint_window=50
[    1.374535] use.voice.path.for.pcm.voip=true
[    1.374539] init.svc.adbd=running
[    1.374543] init.svc.vold=running
[    1.374547] init.svc.healthd=running
[    1.374551] init.svc.ueventd=running
[    1.374555] init.svc.recovery=running
[    1.374559] init.svc.setup_adbd=stopped
[    1.374563] qcom.hw.aac.encoder=true
[    1.374567] qcom.bluetooth.soc=rome
[    1.374570] rild.libpath=/vendor/lib64/libril-qc-qmi-1.so
[    1.374574] wifi.interface=wlan0
[    1.374578] audio.safx.pbe.enabled=true
[    1.374582] audio.dolby.ds2.enabled=false
[    1.374586] audio.dolby.ds2.hardbypass=false
[    1.374590] audio.parser.ip.buffer.size=262144
[    1.374594] audio.offload.min.duration.secs=30
[    1.374598] audio.offload.pcm.16bit.enable=false
[    1.374602] audio.offload.pcm.24bit.enable=true
[    1.374606] audio.offload.track.enable=false
[    1.374610] audio.offload.video=true
[    1.374614] audio.offload.buffer.size.kb=32
[    1.374618] audio.offload.gapless.enabled=true
[    1.374621] audio.offload.multiaac.enable=true
[    1.374625] audio.offload.multiple.enabled=true
[    1.374629] audio.offload.passthrough=false
[    1.374633] audio.deep_buffer.media=true
[    1.374637] media.sf.omx-plugin=libffmpeg_omx.so
[    1.374641] media.sf.extractor-plugin=libffmpeg_extractor.so
[    1.374645] media.stagefright.less-secure=true
[    1.374649] media.stagefright.legacyencoder=true
[    1.374653] media.aac_51_output_enabled=true
[    1.374657] tunnel.audio.encode=false
[    1.374661] persist.cne.feature=1
[    1.374665] persist.gps.qc_nlp_in_use=1
[    1.374669] persist.hwc.enable_vds=1
[    1.374672] persist.loc.nlp_name=com.qualcomm.location
[    1.374676] persist.oem.dump=0
[    1.374680] persist.qfp=false
[    1.374684] persist.demo.hdmirotationlock=false
[    1.374688] persist.rild.nitz_plmn=
[    1.374692] persist.rild.nitz_long_ons_0=
[    1.374696] persist.rild.nitz_long_ons_1=
[    1.374700] persist.rild.nitz_long_ons_2=
[    1.374704] persist.rild.nitz_long_ons_3=
[    1.374708] persist.rild.nitz_short_ons_0=
[    1.374711] persist.rild.nitz_short_ons_1=
[    1.374715] persist.rild.nitz_short_ons_2=
[    1.374719] persist.rild.nitz_short_ons_3=
[    1.374723] persist.rmnet.data.enable=true
[    1.374730] persist.timed.enable=true
[    1.374735] persist.volte_enalbed_by_hw=1
[    1.374740] keyguard.no_require_sim=true
[    1.374744] audio_hal.period_size=160
[    1.374748] telephony.lteOnCdmaDevice=1
[    1.374752] DEVICE_PROVISIONED=1
[    1.374816] persist.audio.fluence.speaker=true
[    1.374822] persist.audio.fluence.voicerec=false
[    1.374826] persist.audio.fluence.voicecall=true
[    1.374853] service.adb.root=1
[    1.374858] security.perf_harden=1
[    1.374996] debug.sf.hw=1
[    1.375001] debug.egl.hw=1
[    1.375005] debug.atrace.tags.enableflags=0
[    1.375101] sys.usb.ffs.ready=1
[    1.375154] dev.pm.dyn_samplingrate=1
[    1.375159] net.bt.name=Android
[    1.375164] net.change=net.bt.name
[    1.375169] persist.sys.dun.override=0
[    1.375172] persist.sys.usb.config=none
[    1.375176] persist.sys.wfd.virtual=0
[    1.375181] persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2=libart.so
[    1.375185] persist.sys.root_access=0
[    1.375210] ril.subscription.types=NV,RUIM
[    1.375215] persist.data.df.agg.dl_pkt=10
[    1.375221] persist.data.df.agg.dl_size=4096
[    1.375225] persist.data.df.dl_mode=5
[    1.375229] persist.data.df.ul_mode=5
[    1.375233] persist.data.df.dev_name=rmnet_usb0
[    1.375238] persist.data.df.iwlan_mux=9
[    1.375242] persist.data.df.mux_count=8
[    1.375246] persist.data.qmi.adb_logmask=0
[    1.375250] persist.data.wda.enable=true
[    1.375253] persist.data.mode=concurrent
[    1.375257] persist.data.netmgrd.qos.enable=true
[    1.375261] persist.radio.multisim.config=dsds
[    1.375266] persist.radio.custom_ecc=1
[    1.375270] persist.radio.hw_mbn_update=0
[    1.375274] persist.radio.sib16_support=1
[    1.375278] persist.radio.sw_mbn_update=0
[    1.375282] persist.radio.ignore_dom_time=5
[    1.375286] persist.radio.apm_sim_not_pwdn=1
[    1.375289] persist.radio.data_ltd_sys_ind=1
[    1.375293] persist.radio.start_ota_daemon=1
[    1.375315]
[    1.375397] I:Saving locale "en_US"
[    1.425722] I:setup_vkeys: could not open /sys/board_properties/virtualkeys.tri-state-key
[    1.509687] I:Saving locale "en_US"
[   86.855631] I:setup_vkeys: could not open /sys/board_properties/virtualkeys.gpio-keys
[   87.497436] I:setup_vkeys: could not open /sys/board_properties/virtualkeys.qpnp_pon
[   87.837035] I:setup_vkeys: could not open /sys/board_properties/virtualkeys.synaptics
[   87.947027] I:Saving locale "en_US"
[   89.438899] I:setup_vkeys: could not open /sys/board_properties/virtualkeys.synaptics
[   91.235108]
[   91.235135]
[   91.235141] Now send the package you want to apply
[   91.235148] to the device with "adb sideload <filename>"...
[  391.264669] I:sideload thread finished
[  455.095789] Restarting adbd...
[  455.098014] I:Saving locale "en_US"
[  457.522294]
[  457.522322]
[  457.522328] Now send the package you want to apply
[  457.522335] to the device with "adb sideload <filename>"...
[  465.535129] Finding update package...
[  465.543920] I:Update location: /sideload/package.zip
[  465.543965] Opening update package...
[  465.544578] I:read key e=3 hash=20
[  465.544711] I:read key e=65537 hash=20
[  465.544835] I:read key e=65537 hash=20
[  465.544870] I:3 key(s) loaded from /res/keys
[  465.544900] Verifying update package...
[  465.691321] I:comment is 1357 bytes; signature 1339 bytes from end
[  482.086174] I:signature (offset: 0x79449fc, length: 1333): 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
[  482.086313] I:whole-file signature verified against RSA key 0
[  482.086341] Update package verification took 16.5 s (result 0).
[  482.086402] Installing update...
[  482.086412] E:Failed to find META-INF/com/android/metadata in update package.
[  482.141584] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.141734] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.141741] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.141745]
[  482.141749] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.141753]  extracting: app_densities.txt
[  482.146604] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.146717] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.146724] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.146729]
[  482.146732] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.146737]  extracting: app_sizes.txt
[  482.151480] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.151604] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.151611] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.151616]
[  482.151620] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.151624]  extracting: bkup_tail.sh
[  482.156530] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.156684] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.156696] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.156701]
[  482.156705] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.156709]  extracting: gapps-remove.txt
[  482.161930] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.162055] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.162062] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.162066]
[  482.162070] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.162095]  extracting: g.prop
[  482.167545] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.167666] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.167678] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.167682]
[  482.167687] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.167691]  extracting: installer.sh
[  482.178535] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.178703] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.178709] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.178713]
[  482.178717] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.178721]  extracting: busybox-arm
[  482.186956] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.187081] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.187088] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.187093]
[  482.187097] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.187101]  extracting: tar-arm
[  482.193179] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.193299] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.193306] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.193311]
[  482.193315] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.193319]  extracting: unzip-arm
[  482.199070] __bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
[  482.199189] MiniUnz 1.01b, demo of zLib + Unz package written by Gilles Vollant
[  482.199195] more info at http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip.html
[  482.199199]
[  482.199203] /sideload/package.zip opened
[  482.199207]  extracting: zip-arm
[  483.658371] mount: mounting /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata on /data failed: Invalid argument
[  483.868727] unknown fuse request opcode 17
[  483.868787] df: /sideload: Function not implemented
[  483.885731] cp: can't create '/sideload/open_gapps_log.txt': Read-only file system
[  488.890148] cp: can't stat '': No such file or directory
[  488.994613] unknown fuse request opcode 17
[  488.994637] df: /sideload: Function not implemented
[  488.995998] cp: can't stat '/sideload/open_gapps_log.txt': No such file or directory
[  488.996844] cp: can't stat '/system/etc/g.prop': No such file or directory
[  488.997573] cp: can't stat '/system/default.prop': No such file or directory
[  488.999141] cp: can't stat '/data/local.prop': No such file or directory
[  489.000750] cp: can't stat '/build.prop': No such file or directory
[  489.001528] cp: can't stat '/system/addon.d/70-gapps.sh': No such file or directory
[  489.028238] logcat read failuretar: can't open '/sideload/open_gapps_debug_logs.tar.gz': Read-only file system
[  489.039148] umount: /data: Invalid argument
[  489.066270] E:Installation error in /sideload/package.zip
[  489.066293] (Status 64)
[  489.074748]
[  491.077467] sideload-host file size 127160119 block size 65536
[  491.077498] sideload_host finished
[  491.082224] I:sideload thread finished
[  491.082279] Restarting adbd...
[  491.082799] Install failedInstallation aborted.
[  491.094032] I:Saving locale "en_US"
[  518.272251] I:Saving locale "en_US"
```

Personally I (ignorantly) wonder if the issue is just with the filesystem table showing `/data` and `/cache` both as `f2fs` and `ext4`, but I have little experience with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the version of TWRP I was using from XDA-Developers had issues. I figured out that by using a slightly older version (3.0.3-0) that everything started working properly again. Frankly, I don't know if using the unbrick guide or anything else helped me, so if you have this issue go ahead and try those at some point too.